# Как сделать автокликер по определенному button`у

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь сделать автоклик по определенному button`y пока на странице не появится надпись Успех.

```js
  if(!$( "div:contains('Успех')" ).length)
    {
      $('button').click();
    }
```

```html
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-lower="1" data-upper="7">1 to 7</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-lower="0" data-upper="0">0</button>
    <button class="btn btn-inverse btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-lower="8" data-upper="14">8 to 14</button>
```

Хотел сделать это в виде тайминтервала но он даже после появления надписи будет проверять страницу на наличие слова? Как это можно сделать по другому?
И к тому же не могу разобраться как отличать кнопки друг от друга, что бы кликать не на все сразу а на одну если их там много.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var div = $('div'), // элемент(ы), где ожидается появление фразы
  button = $('button:eq(1)'), // к примеру, клик по второй кнопке
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (div.filter(':contains("Успех")').length) {
      clearInterval(timer); // если фраза появилась, то останавливаем таймер
      console.log('Приехали');
      return false;
    }
    button.trigger('click');
  }, 1000);

button.on('click', function() {
  console.log('Клик');
});


setTimeout(function() {
  div.text('Успех');
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-lower="1" data-upper="7">1 to 7</button>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-lower="0" data-upper="0">0</button>
<button class="btn btn-inverse btn-lg  btn-block betButton" data-lower="8" data-upper="14">8 to 14</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Браузер жалуется на первую строчку.
**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**